# Wso2 ESB Directory loop with new file filter

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to let the WSO2 ESB scan a local folder recursively, the esb should scan for a xml formatted file(.info.xml or so) in the directory, if the directory contains a file that is not contained in the xml file, the esb should perform a database action and add information about the new file to the xml file.

But how do i let the sequence do this, more important, do i need a Inbound Sequence and what should it do?

Comment: I believe the File Connector should be helpful: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2

Comment: To be able to use the connector - you should add and enable it first: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+Connectors+via+the+Management+Console  and https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+Connectors+via+WSO2+ESB+Tooling

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by using file connector [search](http://%3Cfileconnector.search%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Csource%3E%7B$ctx:source%7D%3C/source%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CfilePattern%3E%7B$ctx:filePattern%7D%3C/filePattern%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CrecursiveSearch%3E%7B$ctx:recursiveSearch%7D%3C/recursiveSearch%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CsetTimeout%3E%7B$ctx:setTimeout%7D%3C/setTimeout%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CsetPassiveMode%3E%7B$ctx:setPassiveMode%7D%3C/setPassiveMode%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CsetSoTimeout%3E%7B$ctx:setSoTimeout%7D%3C/setSoTimeout%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CsetUserDirIsRoot%3E%7B$ctx:setUserDirIsRoot%7D%3C/setUserDirIsRoot%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CsetStrictHostKeyChecking%3E%7B$ctx:setStrictHostKeyChecking%7D%3C/setStrictHostKeyChecking%3E%20%3C/fileconnector.search%3E) operation.

```
<fileconnector.search>
  <source>{$ctx:source}</source>
  <filePattern>{$ctx:filePattern}</filePattern>
  <recursiveSearch>{$ctx:recursiveSearch}</recursiveSearch>
  <setTimeout>{$ctx:setTimeout}</setTimeout>
  <setPassiveMode>{$ctx:setPassiveMode}</setPassiveMode>
  <setSoTimeout>{$ctx:setSoTimeout}</setSoTimeout>
  <setUserDirIsRoot>{$ctx:setUserDirIsRoot}</setUserDirIsRoot>
  <setStrictHostKeyChecking>{$ctx:setStrictHostKeyChecking}</setStrictHostKeyChecking>
</fileconnector.search>
```

filePattern: The pattern of the file to be searched (e.g., [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*.(txt|xml|jar)).

Please check [here](https://medium.com/@lmanohara99/wso2-esb-file-connector-version-2-f789ad389d7d#.365ntqaa5) for sample use case of the search operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the connector[1] and follow link[2] to add and enable the connector and then create the proxy[3].

Sample proxy for file search operation[4].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="FileConnector_search"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="https,http">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.source)" name="source"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.filePattern)" name="filePattern"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.recursiveSearch)" name="recursiveSearch"/>
         <fileconnector.search>
            <source>{$ctx:source}</source>
            <filePattern>{$ctx:filePattern}</filePattern>
            <recursiveSearch>{$ctx:recursiveSearch}</recursiveSearch>
         </fileconnector.search>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Sample request.

```
{
     "source":"/home/vive/Desktop/file",
     "recursiveSearch":"true",
     "filePattern":".*\.xml"
}
```

[1]https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/48bab332-c6a6-4f5a-9b79-17e29c7ad4c6
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Managing+Connectors+in+Your+ESB+Instance
[3]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Custom+Proxy+Template
[4]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2#WorkingwiththeFileConnectorVersion2-search